# Is there is way to select mapping which is not run in past 6 months in informatica

Tags: informatica

I need to find out the mapping name which is not run in last 6 months in informatica folder.

Is there possible?

Could any one help to find out this?

Thanks
Pandia

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could suggest is look for session log. Typically it would be by name session_name.log.

You can filter the log files for the period you are looking for or write a unix script to find the latest running date of each mapping and then filtering it.

Answer (score 0):

Query the OPB_TASK_INST_RUN table for all sessions which have ran over the timespan that you care about